# Restricting valid keys of child interface when parent keys are generic

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to have a child type with a restricted set of valid keys when it extends a parent with generic keys? For example:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor(public value: number) {}
}

interface IParent {
  [key: string]: SomeClass;
}

interface IChild extends IParent {
  a: SomeClass;
  b: SomeClass;
}

const o: IChild = {
  a: new SomeClass(1),
  b: new SomeClass(2),
  c: new SomeClass(3) // I'd like this to be an error
};
```

I'd like anything extending `IParent` to be forced to have `SomeClass` values for all keys, but ideally assigning anything which is not a key explicitly listed in `IChild`'s interface would cause an error.

Is this possible?

Comment: That's not a generic key, that's index signature. Index signatures let you use any key you want, that's why they are used.

Comment: @m93a forgive my ignorance about terminology. I understand the purpose of index signatures is to allow any key, but my case requires the restriction of keys to a subset of all strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a mapped type:

```
type ValidKeys = 'a' | 'b';
type IParent = { [key in ValidKeys]: SomeClass };

interface IChild extends IParent { } // You don't really need this interface.

const o: IChild = {
  a: new SomeClass(1),
  b: new SomeClass(2),
  c: new SomeClass(3),
  // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type 'IChild'.
};
```

But note, this will only protect you from declaring a literal `IChild` with an invalid property. This would still be perfectly valid:

```
const m = {
  a: new SomeClass(1),
  b: new SomeClass(2),
  c: new SomeClass(3),
};

const o: IChild = m;
```

You could also make `IParent` generic to be able to have multiple children,

```
type IParent<T extends string> = { [key in T]: SomeClass };

type IHasAB = IParent<'a' | 'b'>;
type IHasXY = IParent<'x' | 'y'>;

const ab: IHasAB = {
    a: new SomeClass(1),
    b: new SomeClass(2),
};
const xy: IHasXY = {
    x: new SomeClass(3),
    y: new SomeClass(4),
};
```

Comment: If I want the `ValidKeys` to be inferred from the child interface is it possible? There will be many child interfaces with different keys, I just want to restrict them to all having values of `SomeClass`.

Comment: @philraj I think a better solution may be a generic `IParent`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks I think this'll do.